# Java logger message template doesn't work

Tags: java, logging

I was using a logger, `java.util.logging.Logger`, in my program. First I wrote something like this:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "message"+str);
```

and the IDE told me I can use a message template to improve efficiency, so the IDE changed the above to:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "message{0}", str);
```

but when I ran the program the output was just:

```
11:43:05[INFO]message{0}
```

What is wrong with the above code? I have searched about the method and every site tells me that it is the right syntax, but it just doesn't seem to work.

**Edit**: I noticed another thread discussing this and the answer was to escape single quote. However, my original code hasn't any single quotes in the string

Comment: Does your 'message' contain any single quotes? The second form is definitely superior: no string substitution is done if the message never gets logged (e.g. if logging is off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `MessageFormat` class `log.info(MessageFormat.format("message{0}",string))`
The string will replace the "{0}".

Comment: Note: this is not super efficient either because the string substitution will be done irrespective of whether any log message ever gets generated. Think about if logging is switched off.